# Extremely low FPS running XCOM 2

Tags: xcom-2

[image]

As you can tell, when I'm in the Avenger main screen as well as watching cutscenes, my fps drops significantly to around 10-30 fps, as well as my gpu reaching temperatures around 73 degrees C.

Basically, almost every part of the game has a significant visual lag even though I have a mid-tier gaming rig.  This was tested on running low -> high settings, and the issues are still prevalent on low and high.

The issues:

- Low framerate in Avenger HQ
- Extremely low framerate when in Dropship
- Low framerate in combat after concealment is lifted
- In-game cinematics also have low framerate.

Anyone else getting this, and have a fix for this? Is this just a part of poor optimisation?

Comment: Sounds like the lack of proper optimization, usual in games just after their release.

Comment: I was having mid 20-30 fps in the Avenger screen on my 970, but the game defaulted to 8xMSAA.  Dropping down to 2x, or FXAA pushed my frame rates back up to 50-60.

Comment: Looking at [the steam reviews](http://store.steampowered.com/app/268500/#app_reviews_hash), bad performance is a very common complaint about the game. I guess we will have to wait for version 1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed in the first performance patch that Firaxis pushed through.